# docker entrypoint script won't echo output inside `trap` function

Tags: bash, docker, shell, docker-compose, entry-point

I want to be able to trap a SIGINT, then perform a function, then stop the container, all with `docker-compose`.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

backup_dir="/backup"

# Define a function to handle the SIGINT signal (graceful shutdown)
echo "[+] Postgres customer_entrypoint ran."

shutdown() {
    echo "[+] Backing up database before shutdown."
    pg_dumpall --on-conflict-do-nothing --column-inserts -U "$POSTGRES_USER" > "/backups/backup_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).sql"
    pg_ctl -D "$PGDATA" -m fast -w stop
}

trap shutdown SIGINT
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh postgres &                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
wait $!
```

Here is my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3.3'                                                                                                                                                                           
services:                                                                                                                                                                               
  postgres:                                                                                                                                                                            
    container_name: postgres                                                                                                                                                                  
    build:                                                                                                                                                                                     
      context: ./postgres                                                                                                                                                                                        
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-postgres.dev                                                                                                                                                                                          
    image: postgres-my:latest                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    restart: always                                                                                                                                                                                           
    env_file:                                                                                                                                                                                             
      - ./.env.dev.db                                                                                                                                                                                             
    ports:                                                                                                                                                                                          
        - '127.0.0.1:5432:5432'                                                                                                                                                                                       
    volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      - ./postgres/backups:/backups                                                                                                                                                                                     
      - postgres_data_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    stop_signal: SIGINT                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                        
volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                          
    postgres_data_dev:
```

I run the container in attached mode with `docker compose` like this:

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev up --build
```

I can see `[+] Postgres customer_entrypoint ran.` appear in the `docker-compose` output so I know the script is running. If I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, `docker-compose` output immediately shows this:

```
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping postgres  ... done
```

and no other output. However I know the shutdown function ran as it created the backup file.  However I thought I would see `[+] Backing up database before shutdown.` before the output above.

If I run `docker-compose`, and then run `docker logs postgres --follow` then I see the output.

Why can't I see any `echo` output from my `trap` function with `docker-compose`? How can I adjust so I can see output? The main problem is I can't see stderr either so I don't know if my logic is broken when changing code. How can I fix this?

Comment: Tangentially, the first two bytes of the file need to be exactly `#!`, otherwise the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is not valid.

Comment: The comment says `SIGTERM` but you actually then trap `SIGINT`. Bash provides a pseudo-signal `EXIT` which you can trap, too.

Comment: @Tripleee Fixed typos

Comment: More to the point, can you see that the signal you are receiving is actually `SIGINT`? I'm thinking the `EXIT` trap would be more suitable.

Comment: Tried EXIT, same issue. I think this is a buffer problem with docker-compose. because as I mentioned, I see all the output with `docker logs --follow` no problem.